# How can I assert that no route matches in a Rails integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, url-routing, integration-testing

I have a Rails 3 integration test which tests my routes. It contains tests such as:

```
assert_routing(
    "/#{@category.url.path}/#{@foo.url.path}",
    { :controller => 'foo', :action => 'show', :category => @category.to_param, :foo => @foo.to_param }
)
```

I would also like to test a case where no routes should match. Obviously, testing generation has no meaning in this case, so I just need the inverse of assert_recognizes. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
assert_not_recognized('/adfhkljkdhasjklhjkldfahsjkhdf')
```

Any ideas, short of wrapping assert_recognizes in an assert_raises block (which is actually not so terrible, now that I think about it)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
  def test_no_routes_match_when_neither_foo_nor_bar_exist
    assert_raises(ActionController::RoutingError) do
      assert_recognizes({}, '/category/this-is-neither-a-foo-nor-a-bar')
    end
  end
```

Slightly silly, but it gets the job done.

Note that this **does not** work with Rails 4. [See the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21662764/58994) for a Rails 4 solution.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer, at least as of Rails 4.  The "assert_recognizes({} ..." will fail if either 1) the given path is not recognized at all, or 2) if it is recognized but as something other than {} (which should always be the case, because a recognized route will contain :action and :controller keys).

Comment: I can't really remember which Rails version I was using when I had this issue. It was over two years ago. :)

Comment: I can confirm that this worked in Rails 3 (3.2.16), but fails in Rails 4 (4.0.2). I'll add another variant as separate answer.

Comment: In Rails 5 this works for me except replace the assert recognizes statement with the http verb and route you are testing: get '/category/this-is-neither-a-foo-nor-a-bar'

Comment: I wonder how to cleanly test for unavailability of `#new`? It seems that `new` is treated as *id* in `whatever/new` if routing includes *show* but not *new*. I want to prohibit new/create and test nothing is called there.

Answer (score 12):

There is a similar way for checking this in **Rails 4** by asserting on the **UrlGenerationError** exception:

```
def test_no_routes_match_when_neither_foo_nor_bar_exist
  assert_raises(ActionController::UrlGenerationError) do
    get '/category/this-is-neither-a-foo-nor-a-bar'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

By calling #recognize_path you wont receive a **false**. Instead you'll get an error, but then you found the clue you were looking for.

```
test "No routes match when neither_foo_nor_ bar exist" do
  begin 
    assert_not(Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(
        'category/this-is-neither-a-foo-nor-a-bar'))
  rescue ActionController::RoutingError => error
    assert error.message.start_with? "No route matches"
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `method_missing(selector, *args, &block)`?
Defined [Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-method_missing)