# Rails tests with activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activeadmin, minitest

I am using activeadmin on my Rails project and I would like to know how to make test on it. I looked over on internet but there is no documentation about it.
I have a settings resource, and I disabled the possibility to create a new one or to delete it.

I would like to know how to test these routes doesn’t exists or another way to be sure it can’t be accessible.
In my actual though I was trying to assert this page to be a 404 but the test seems to throw this error (which is what I tried to test !!!): `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/settings"}`

**I don't use Rspec but Minitest** from Rails.
Thanks for your help !

**My activeadmin file**:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Setting do
    actions :all, except: [:new, :destroy]
    …
end
```

**My tests**:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Admin::SettingsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   include Devise::TestHelpers
   setup :initialize_settings

   test 'should throw 404 if trying to access new action' do
     get :new
     assert_response 404
   end

   def initialize_settings
     sign_in users(:one)
   end
end
```

**My project**:

- Rails 4.2
- Ruby 2.2.0
- Minitest (NOT RSPEC)

Comment: if you remove the :new from this line actions :all, except: [:new, :destroy] do you still get that same error? Have you tried instead of assert_response ... doing something like this value(response).must_respond_with 404

Answer (score 0):

What you are needing are integration tests, specifically ones that will test the routes, or in your case, the absence of routes. The non-existent actions will raise `ActionController::RoutingError`.

```
# test/routes/admin/settings_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class Admin::SettingsRouteTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest  
  test 'create' do
    assert_raises(ActionController::RoutingError) do
      post '/admin/settings'
    end
  end

  test 'destroy' do
    assert_raises(ActionController::RoutingError) do
      delete '/admin/settings/1'
    end
  end

  test 'edit' do
    assert_routing '/admin/settings/1/edit', controller: 'admin/settings', action: 'edit', id: '1'
  end

  test 'index' do
    assert_routing '/admin/settings', controller: 'admin/settings', action: 'index'
  end

  test 'new' do
    assert_routing '/admin/settings/new', controller: 'admin/settings', action: 'show', id: 'new'
  end

  test 'update' do
    assert_routing({ method: 'patch', path: '/admin/settings/1' }, { controller: 'admin/settings', action: 'update', id: '1' })
  end
end
```

Notice that the `new` action falls back to a `show` action with an id of 'new'.

OBSERVATION: If you are removing the `:new` action, you probably intended to remove the `:create` action too so that no records can be created through that route.

```
# app/admin/setting.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Setting do
  actions :all, except: [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

Comment: Actually, this post solved the problem for Rails 4: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21662764/3700317